# Type is not assignable to type | Learning type script and story book at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have setup Story book, and am attempting to convert the default button component from JS to TSX. I haven't used typescript before other than adding an any type to an interface to just get it working. The error is pointed to this line

const Template: Story = (args) => **//ERROR HERE <Button //** {...args} />;

Above is where in my editor it is pointing out the type error. I am not quite sure why, so any guidance on why this is happening would be great, I'm happy to read up, but some pointers in the right direction would be great.

Here is my `Button.stories.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Story, Meta} from "@storybook/react"

import { Button, ButtonProps } from './Button';

export default {
  title: 'Example/Button',
  component: Button,
  argTypes: {
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
  },
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<ButtonProps> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {
  primary: true,
  label: 'Button',
};

export const Secondary = Template.bind({});
Secondary.args = {
  label: 'Button',
};

export const Large = Template.bind({});
Large.args = {
  size: 'large',
  label: 'Button',
};

export const Small = Template.bind({});
Small.args = {
  size: 'small',
  label: 'Button',
};
```

Here is my `Button.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import './button.css';

export interface ButtonProps {
  primary?: boolean;
  backgroundColor?: string;
  size?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
  label?: string;
  onClick?:(
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
  ) => void;
};

/**
 * Primary UI component for user interaction
 */
export const Button = ({ primary, backgroundColor, size, label, ...props }) => {
  const mode = primary ? 'storybook-button--primary' : 'storybook-button--secondary';
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={['storybook-button', `storybook-button--${size}`, mode].join(' ')}
      style={backgroundColor && { backgroundColor }}
      {...props}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Type '{ primary?: boolean; backgroundColor?: string; size?: "large" | "small" | "medium"; label?: string; onClick?: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void; }' is not assignable to type '{ [x: string]: any; primary: any; backgroundColor: any; size: any; label: any; }'.
  Property 'primary' is optional in type '{ primary?: boolean; backgroundColor?: string; size?: "large" | "small" | "medium"; label?: string; onClick?: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void; }' but required in type '{ [x: string]: any; primary: any; backgroundColor: any; size: any; label: any; }'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Button` component accepts props that are different from your declared `ButtonProps`

Solution 1: Use the Button props in your Button component decleration

```
export const Button = ({ primary, backgroundColor, size, label, onClick}:ButtonProps) => {
  const mode = primary ? 'storybook-button--primary' : 'storybook-button--secondary';
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={['storybook-button', `storybook-button--${size}`, mode].join(' ')}
      style={backgroundColor && { backgroundColor }}
      onClick
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Solution 2: export a specific type for the actual props that your component uses:

```
export interface ActualButtonProps {
  primary: boolean;
  backgroundColor: string;
  size: "small" | "medium" | "large";
  label: string;
  props: {[x:string]:any}
}

export const Button = ({ primary, backgroundColor, size, label, ...props }) => {
  const mode = primary ? 'storybook-button--primary' : 'storybook-button--secondary';
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className={['storybook-button', `storybook-button--${size}`, mode].join(' ')}
      style={backgroundColor && { backgroundColor }}
      {...props}
    >
      {label}
    </button>
  );
};
```

and in your storybook:

```
const Template: Story<ActualButtonProps> = (args) => <Button {...args} />;
```